# JQuery - Get a error mesage if there is no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So I have completed my Website as I wanted and now I'm just at the last point to get an error message if my movie isn't found. So it means that I have an API that returns JSON. If a person writes invalid movie like "ifeahaef" it returns null and I wonder if it possible to make in Jquery an error like "No Movies Were Found!" like right under the search bar? Right now my site looks like this

[image: my site right now]

and this is how I want it

[image: What I want]

I don't know if my code is necessary but I can post my JS in case, maybe it will be easier to see.

```
function callAjax(input) 
{ 
var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" + input; 

$.ajax({ 
type:'GET', 
url: url, 
success: function(data) 
{ 
console.log('SUCCESS'); 
$('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);
$('#release').html("Release: " + data.release);
$('#vote').html("Vote: " + data.vote);
$('#overview').html("Overview: " + data.overview);
$('#poster').html('<img src="' + data.poster + '" width=250 height=450 />'); 
$('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.trailer + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");



},
error: function(request, status, err) 
{ 
console.log('ERROR'); 
} 
}); 
} 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 

var input = $('#s').val();
callAjax(input); 
}); 

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MovieTrailerbase</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

    <h1>The MovieTrailer search</h1>

    <form id="searchForm" method="post">
        <fieldset>

            <input id="s" type="text" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />

            <div id="searchInContainer">
                <input type="radio" name="check" value="site" id="searchSite" checked />
                <label for="searchSite" id="siteNameLabel">Search movie</label>

                <input type="radio" name="check" value="web" id="searchWeb" />
                <label for="searchWeb">Search series</label>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

<aside>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="release"></div>
<div id="vote"></div>
<div id="overview"></div>
<br>
<div id="trailer"></div>
</aside>

<div id="poster"></div>


</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: It's certainly possible, but nobody's going to be able to tell you how without seeing your HTML as well. In general, don't show images of your output--instead give us the code to recreate it.

Comment: Okey doing it right now :)

Comment: You know anyone can click 'edited' and see the question before the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple understanding, if any API is now throwing error, it is considered as success. Now what you can do is handle this case like

```
function(response){
    if(response){
        // Do your stuff
        $("#lblerror").addClass("hide"); // Hide label if movie found
    }
    else{
        $("#lblerror").text("No Movie found");
        $("#lblerror").removeClass("hide"); // Show Label if no movie found
    }
}
```

A simple way to do this is add a error label in your HTML

```
<label class="error hide" id="lblerror"></label>
```

Comment: But I found a problem, when searching for new movie again, the lable is still stuck there even if its found

Comment: Hmm, its still the same problem sir.

Comment: @WeInThis I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g2rve0bq/). Also I have tried to use **Declarative Programming** concept. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, its to complicated for me because I don't know how to set it up with mine.. http://jsfiddle.net/2893qn7L/ here you go a Link for mine

Comment: @WeInThis [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2893qn7L/1/). Also just to explain you, if you dont get data, you remove `hide` class to show it, so when you find it, add class 'hide' to error label. Also just an add-on, add hide class on typing. This gives feedback to user and make UX little better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93094/discussion-between-weinthis-and-rajesh).

Comment: Hmm, I did what you said but its still left in the HTML, even if I change to new movie it still there above the picture that says "No movies found"

Comment: So the problem is now that If I have a movie and then search for a new movie, the "No movie found" is getting above the picture"

Answer (score 0):

1) Include an `Error` field in your JSON returned object from server. Your JSON object must have the following fields:

```
   title
   release
   vote
   overview
   poster
   trailer
   Error
```

2) You have to do the following using your server side language:

1. Get movie name from request
2. If movie found then create a JSON with movie data and `Error = false` and fill the rest of JSON with the movie data.

   2.1. Else create a JSON with `Error = true`. No need to fill the rest of fields
3. Return JSON to client side

3) Then in your Ajax `success` callback look if there was an error:

```
$.ajax({ 
 type:'GET', 
 url: url, 
 success: function(data){ 
     if(!data.Error){
       console.log('SUCCESS'); 
       $('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);
       $('#release').html("Release: " + data.release);
       $('#vote').html("Vote: " + data.vote);
       $('#overview').html("Overview: " + data.overview);
       $('#poster').html('<img src="' + data.poster + '" width=250     height=450 />'); 
       $('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.trailer + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");

     }else{ 
         alert("Movie not found");
     }
 },
 error: function(request, status, err){ 
    console.log('ERROR'); 
 } 
}); 
}
```

Comment: It gave me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Error' of null` in Console

Comment: Did you include in the Server side? It's case sensitive.

Comment: In my server im using server, so what I have is that if the object isnt found, then catch a Jsonexception, Can that be the issue?

Comment: If there was an error, you have to generate a JSON with `Error = true` You don't have to return null to cliend side. Wich server side language do you use?

Comment: Hmm, Im doing in Java @anmarti how so?

Comment: @WeInThis Please see my answer again. If you don't succeed please post your server side code.

Comment: No problem sir! I got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your response is structured. But i'd aim for something like this.

```
if(data.length <= 0 || data == null){
     $('#element-to-add-message-to').html('No titles found....');
     return;
}
```